# Serving static content from port 8080?

Tags: javascript, jquery, static-content

Is it a bad practice to serve JS (static content basically - css, js and images) on port 8080 instead of HTTP (80)? If so, why? If not, are there any advantages at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

80 is the standard http port and mostly all firewalls are configured to allow traffic to this port. Any other port may need specific port privileges configured in firewall.

Comment: So yes it bad practice. Don't do it - you'll alienate some of your users.